# Why plutonium and uranium are especially susceptible to do fission?

Tags: nuclear-physics, binding-energy, elements

Why plutonium and uranium are especially susceptible to do fission? Are there any other elements that can also be subject to fission?

Answer (score 2):

It is not the elements but the isotopes U-235 and Pu-239. Those two have an odd number of neutrons, and can fission by absorbing a thermal neutron. It is the pairing energy (spin-up and spin-down) that is the cause of this.

Answer (score 0):

All of the nuclei - except the proton - are susceptible to fission.

The typical binding energy of a nucleon (particles of the core of the atoms, i.e. neutron or proton) is around $\mathrm{5MeV}$ in most atoms. Hitting a nucleus with *anything* sometimes of this energy, it will fissile.

However, not this is what you likely want. The ${}^{235}\mathrm{U}$ and the ${}^{239}\mathrm{Pu}$ are special, that we can do *chain reaction* with it: the neutrons leaving the fissiled nucleus can fissile other nuclei.

This chain reaction capability is a very special feature:

- there are at least 1300 nuclei known (most of them is very short living)
- roughly 130 of them are stable
- there are capable to do around 10-12 nuclear reactions

Despite that, only these two are usable to make nuclear chain reaction from them.

Comment: @john Ok. Btw, also heavier nuclei would be capable to this reaction. As far I know, roughly from Californium, all of the nuclei would be usable for fission. But they are very costly to produce (typically, from uranium, in nuclear reactors). As far I know, also $U^{233}$ is usable for fission, but it can't be mined (it decayed long ago), rather it has to be produced from $Th^{232}$ in a more complex process. And also $Np^{237}$ is usable in nuclear reactors, but far lesser useful as $U^{235}$.

Answer (score -1):

The n/p ratio, that is,  neutron to proton ratio is much greater than 1.5.So they are highly fission able. Radioactivity is a nuclear phenomenon. No electrons are responsible for this.

Comment: why is this ratio important?  or rather why is this specific value important?  Why is a ratio $>1$ not enough?

Comment: This does not explain why U-238, with more neutrons, has a lower fission cross-section than U-235, which has fewer neutrons.  Neutron-to-proton ratio is a good predictor for stability against $\beta^-$ or $\beta^+$ decay, but fission has more details involved.